# Jerking and knocking

Tags: ford, diesel, fusion

My Ford Fusion (diesel) runs like a tractor when it's cold in the morning. After getting warmer will get jerks and knocks at some intervals. Often at about 2000 rpm. After more than an hour driving comes jerking and knocking tighter and then tapping and jerking is strong and finally the engine brakes in and dies. After long cooling it can run again after which everything is repeated.

The Ford workshop does not find the fault but has replaced the glow plugs and injector cables.

No fault code for injectors is given.

Could it be the ERG valve?

Regards,
Gunnar

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely check the egr-clean it up and see if its free moving-a stuck (even partially) open egr will cause excessive air into the mix and easily stall it at different temperatures

Comment: I will try that :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be an EGR, but stalling the engine by it is rather unusual. You can also check for signs of air bubbles in the fuel hoses, although lack of fuel should cause low fuel pressure on common rail errors. 
Which TDCI engine is this? You might start by disconnecting wires leading to EGR, blanking it or taking out for cleaning to check if the valve itself is actually the culprit here.